# Data import SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql

I'm adding data into a table in my database from a VB application. But, I need to know, is it possible that some of the data I added can be imported to another table?

example:

```
table1(ID,FisrtName,LastName) data are added completely  
table 2 specific (FirstName, LastName)
```

Answer (score 2):

`insert into table2 (FirstName,LastName) select FirstName,LastName from table1;`

Answer (score 1):

Use a Trigger AFTER INSERT on the table 1 and the thing is done automatically after inserting the data on table 1 or if the data has already been inserted then use a select insert statement like.

INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(FirstName,LastName)
SELECT T.FirstName,T.LastName FROM dbo.Table1 AS T

And that should be it.